# Converting *.wma to *.mp3 by SHELL-script with mplayer, lame, and find

Tags: bash, shell, mp3, wma

I want to convert my older *.wma files into *.mp3. For that purpose I found a short script to convert with using mplayer + lame (found here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/508625/python-v2-7-requires-to-install-plugins-to-play-media-files-of-the-following-t).

This works fine in a single directory. Now I wanted to improve it that way, that it's able to work with 'find'. Its intended to find a *.wma-file and then calling the script to convert that file to *.mp3.

Here is the script:

```
FILENAME=$1
FILEPATH="$(dirname $1)"
BASENAME="$(basename $1)"

mplayer -vo null -vc dummy -af resample=44100 -ao pcm:waveheader "$FILENAME"
lame -m j -h --vbr-new -b 320 audiodump.wav -o "`basename "$FILENAME" .wma`.mp3"
echo "Path: $FILEPATH" # just to see if its correct
echo "File: $BASENAME" # just to see if its correct
rm -f audiodump.wav
rm -f "$FILENAME"
```

At the moment I'm dealing with the issue, that the script put the converted *.mp3 in the directory which the console is working with (e.g. /home/user/ instead of /home/user/files/ where the *.wma comes from).

What can I do to let the script putting the new *.mp3 into the same directory as the *.wma?
If I want to use 'mv' within the script I get trouble with embedded spaces in the *.wma-filenames.

Thanks for any hints. I thought about setting the IFS to tab or newline, but I wounder if there is a better way to deal with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `basename` is stripping *both* the `.wma` extension *and* the path leading to the file. And you only want the `.wma` stripping.

So the answer is not to use `basename` and instead just do the `.wma` stripping yourself (with [Parameter Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02)).

```
outfile=${FILENAME%.wma}
lame -m j -h --vbr-new -b 320 audiodump.wav -o "$outfile.mp3"
```

(Note that I used lowercase `$outfile`. Generally `$ALL_CAPS` variables are reserved for the shell/terminal/environment and should be avoided in scripts.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's something that uses ffmpeg for the conversion (after using ffprobe for figuring out what the bit_rate should be). It's based off of what I found in (https://askubuntu.com/questions/508278/how-to-use-ffmpeg-to-convert-wma-to-mp3-recursively-importing-from-txt-file). But I didn't have access to avprobe, so had to hunt for an alternative.

First navigate to the directory with all your files and run the following from your shell:

```
find . -type f | grep wma$ > wma-files.txt
```

Once that's done, you can put this into a script and run it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

readarray -t files < wma-files.txt

ffprobe=<your_path_here>/ffprobe
ffmpeg=<your_path_here>/ffmpeg
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    out=${file%.wma}.mp3
    bit_rate=`$ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=bit_rate -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$file"`
    $ffmpeg -i "$file" -vn -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab "$bit_rate" -f mp3 "$out"
done
```

This will save the mp3 files alongside the wma ones.